# Retrieve all items ids from dynamodb java using DynamoDbMapper

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

My goal is to retrieve all item's ids. For that, I'm gonna use Java and DynamoDBMapper.
The way to do it is to use *scan*. Right now, my code looks like this:

```
DynamoDBScanExpression paginatedScanListExpression = new DynamoDBScanExpression()
                .withLimit(10000)
                .withProjectionExpression("id");

var paginatedList = mapper.scanPage(MyObject.class, paginatedScanListExpression);
```

The problem is that I get only 600 ids per request. I'm aware of a DynamoDB 1MB per query limit, but still, it seems that 600 ids are too little for one request. Does anyone know how I can fetch all the ids more efficiently?

Comment: A single Query operation can retrieve a maximum of 1 MB of data. [This limit applies before any FilterExpression is applied to the results.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html).

Comment: *An important note is that any limitations on reads are applied in Step 1, before a* **filter or projection expression** *is applied. If you retrieve 100KB of data in Step 1 but filter it down to 1KB of data in Step 2, you will consume the Read Capacity Units for 100KB of data, not the 1KB that it was filtered to.* [Some non official dynamoDB wiki](https://www.dynamodbguide.com/filtering/)

Comment: @dbl okay, I got it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try with ScanSpec with ProjectionExpression which specifies the attributes you want in the scan result.

```
ScanSpec scanSpec = new ScanSpec().withProjectionExpression("id");

    try {
        ItemCollection<ScanOutcome> items = table.scan(scanSpec);

        Iterator<Item> iter = items.iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            Item item = iter.next();
            System.out.println(item.toString());
        }

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Unable to scan the table:");
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

Reference - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.Java.04.html